# if/then when changing multiple text values

Tags: r

I have a field with county names that need to be cleaned up.

Snapshot of freq output:

```
               Eaton     861      3.83          27.64      3.83          27.59
               EATON       2      0.01          27.64      0.01          27.60
              Ingham    4060     18.06          49.04     18.04          48.97
             InghamI       1      0.00          49.05      0.00          48.97
            InghamMI       1      0.00          49.05      0.00          48.98
           Washtenaw    3945     17.55          99.16     17.53          99.01
           WASHTENAW       1      0.00          99.17      0.00          99.02
         Washtenawas       1      0.00          99.17      0.00          99.02
```

When I only had one to change, this worked:

```
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="EATON","Eaton",LSSCM$county)
```

But now I have a bunch and i know that LSSCM$county at the end, means "copy everything else over", so this obviously doesn't work. The results show only the last one was fixed.  The earlier ones were overwritten by the later ones:

```
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="EATON","Eaton",LSSCM$county)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="InghamI","Ingham",LSSCM$county)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="InghamMI","Ingham",LSSCM$county)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="WASHTENAW","Washtenaw",LSSCM$county)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="Washtenawas","Washtenaw",LSSCM$county)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="Washtenaww","Washtenaw",LSSCM$county)
```

How do write the code so I can include all of the ifs and only at the end, copy everything else over that wasn't changed?

Comment: I guess you may need a `amatch` or `adist` to match and create a single group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because, you are not incrementing your results in `LSSCM$county2`.
At each `ifelse` you are applying the full columns of `LSSCM$county`, so each time you are trying to replace a character, you are removing the previous one by copying the column `LSSCM$county`.

Try to do:

```r
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county=="EATON","Eaton",LSSCM$county)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county2=="InghamI","Ingham",LSSCM$county2)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county2=="InghamMI","Ingham",LSSCM$county2)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county2=="WASHTENAW","Washtenaw",LSSCM$county2)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county2=="Washtenawas","Washtenaw",LSSCM$county2)
LSSCM$county2 <- ifelse(LSSCM$county2=="Washtenaww","Washtenaw",LSSCM$county2)
```

---

**Alternative** to `ifelse` for replacing matches

You could have the use of `str_replace_all` from the package `stringi`. If you defined first the pattern you are looking to replace (called `original` here) and the replacement pattern (called `new`), you can do:

```r
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

original = c("EATON","InghamI","InghamMI","WASHTENAW", "Washtenawas","Washtenaww")
new = c("Eaton","Ingham", "Ingham","Washtenaw", "Washtenaw", "Washtenaw" )

df %>% mutate(County2 = str_replace_all(county, original, new))

        county       value   County2
1        EATON -0.93848304     Eaton
2      InghamI  0.09535401    Ingham
3     InghamMI -0.46281942    Ingham
4    WASHTENAW -1.46888216 Washtenaw
5  Washtenawas  0.15268651 Washtenaw
6   Washtenaww  1.77376261 Washtenaw
7        EATON -0.64807093     Eaton
8      InghamI -0.19981748    Ingham
9     InghamMI  0.68924373    Ingham
10   WASHTENAW  0.03614551 Washtenaw
11 Washtenawas  1.94353631 Washtenaw
12  Washtenaww  0.73721373 Washtenaw
13       EATON  2.32133393     Eaton
14     InghamI  0.34890935    Ingham
15    InghamMI -1.13391666    Ingham
16   WASHTENAW  0.42133527 Washtenaw
17 Washtenawas -0.92455626 Washtenaw
18  Washtenaww -1.00706237 Washtenaw
19       EATON -0.18947433     Eaton
20     InghamI  0.93391670    Ingham
21    InghamMI  0.34391000    Ingham
22   WASHTENAW  0.81402028 Washtenaw
23 Washtenawas  0.91534100 Washtenaw
24  Washtenaww -0.17185213 Washtenaw
```

**Data**

```r
original = c("EATON","InghamI","InghamMI","WASHTENAW", "Washtenawas","Washtenaww")
new = c("Eaton","Ingham", "Ingham","Washtenaw", "Washtenaw", "Washtenaw" )

df = data.frame(county = rep(original, 4),
                value = rnorm(24))
```

Comment: You're welcome ! I edited my answer to provided you an alternative (easier?) way to replace characters of the column `county`. Maybe you can be interested by that